# MySql Workbench installer requires Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Package to be installed, but it already is installed

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've looked everywhere online, but it doesn't look like anyone has been able to resolve this issue.

When I download and try to install MySql Workbench, I get prompted to install Visual C++ Redistributable package (2015) to be installed. The wizard then takes me directly to [this website](https://dev.mysql.com/resources/wb62_prerequisites.html) in order to install it.

However, whenever I try to install either, it just tells me they're already installed.

After googling this for about an hour, I found some other people had this problem which apparently was resolved by [following the instructions from this website](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=62141). I downloaded instaedit and followed the instructions, but I continue to get the same error.

I've been at this for two days now and am going to go crazy. If someone can help me with this I'd be very grateful. I'm using Windows 10,

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It turns out that VC++ 2017 redistributables are the culprit because they delete the registry keys used by VC++ 2015 redistributables.
See [this Microsoft Developer Community page](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/262841/vc-runtime-redistributable-update-deletes-registry.html) for solution (TL;DR; you have to [repair](https://web.archive.org/web/20170817125955/https://support.solarwinds.com/Success_Center/Network_Performance_Monitor_(NPM)/Repair_Microsoft_C___Redistributable) VC++ **2017** redistributables as this will restore missing 2015 registry keys).

This process is [as Eric describes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172345/mysql-workbench-installer-requires-visual-c-2015-redistributable-package-to-be#comment98625496_51444345):

> The steps are essentially: go to Programs in Control Panel (or "Add or Remove Programs" in Windows 10's "Settings"), find the Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable, click it and choose Change/Modify, then choose "Repair

Comment: it made it for me. I do not have the c++ 2017 error but :1: The action 'Install' for product 'MySQL Server 8.0.11' failed. I give up and change to mariadb.

Comment: That Worked with Win 10, and Latest version of MysSql Workbench

Comment: OP here -- switching solution to this one because, two years later, someone finally solved the problem.

Comment: This solution worked for me, but the "repair" link above no longer works.  The steps are essentially: go to Programs in Control Panel (or "Add or Remove Programs" in Windows 10's "Settings"), find the Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable, click it and choose Change/Modify, then choose "Repair"

Comment: Thanks for the solution.
Just to clarify, it worked for me on a win 10 (1803) only after running "repair" on Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x64)  - 14.14.26405.
I also have a later version (26706) also installed, and running "repair" on it did not do the job.

Comment: Microsoft C++ Redistributable Repair List:  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x64)  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable (x86)  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x64)  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable (x86)  
1. Open Programs and Features.  
a. Start > Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features.  
b. Search > Programs and Features.  
2. Select Microsoft C++ Redistributable, right-click and click on Change.  
3. On Microsoft C++ Redistributable Setup, click on Repair.  
4. Click on Close once setup is successful.

Answer (score 26):

I got it working running latest mysql-workbench.msi from cmd.exe with escalated permissions:

1. run cmd.exe as Administrator
2. cd to folder where msi resides
3. run it

Comment: Superb. This is what worked on Win10 Enterprise version 1607.

Comment: This did not work for me - if you have the Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable installed, see solution about repairing the redistributable; that one worked for me.

Comment: @John you have to do both sometimes.I had to repart VC++ redistributable and then do what zposloncec has mentioned.

Answer (score 12):

Tried and tested.

I was getting an error: mysql workbench requires the visual c++ 2019 redistributable package to be installed

I visited the link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Downloaded and installed the file, And boom it was working.

Comment: thank you for the link

Answer (score 8):

None of the solutions work for me until I install the old version: 
mysql-workbench-community-6.3.8-winx64.msi

Answer (score 6):

I tried the solutions posted here, but continued to run into the same errors. Oddly enough, installing an older version of Workbench actually resolved the problem. I wasn't exactly happy about this because I went to school and they showed us the most recent one, but this is the easiest and most direct solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you have Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x64) or (x86), please **uninstall** them both and **run again the MySql Workbench installer**.

After the installation is done, **install** back Microsoft Visual **C++ 2017** Redistributable packages.

Here is the link to download MS V C++ 2017 Redist. :
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: This works perfectly for me. In my case, I had installed Visual Studio 2017 first so the C++ redistributable libraries came with that and would not allow the 2015 older versions to be installed after-the-fact. Removing and re-installing with proper order of operations is the answer for me.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I did a fresh Win10 install, and had no Visual C++ installed. Running mysql-workbench-community-8.0.18-winx64.msi said I needed to have VC++ and .NET installed, but the link it provided was a 404. I installed VC++ 2017 from your link, then ran workbench installer and now all works.

Answer (score 3):

First try to uninstall completely Visual C++ Redistributable package (2015) and install it again. If that does not help please try something else:

Open regedit and try to find key
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x64
or
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x64
if you see that keys check value Installed=1 (DWORD)

If you found these keys and you got message about not installed c-runtime try to use processmonitor from sysinternals https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor and check if you have access to registry.

If you don't have these keys in your registry you can try to create it manually 
 and see if that helps.

Comment: I tried all of these things and none worked. I did, however, find a solution which I posted in the thread.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem and wanted to avoid installing an old version. I got success downloading the 32 bit visual studio version from:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48145

I suspect it has something to do with the pathing in the installer which only identifies the 32 bit version of the visual studio library.

Answer (score 3):

- Uninstall VC Redistributable 2017 x64 x86 from your computer.
- Install VC Redistributable 2015 x64 x86 to your computer.
- Install MySQL Workbench 8.0 to your computer.
- Run MySQL Workbench 8.0 and close it.
- Install VC Redistributable 2017 x86 x64 to your computer.
- Run MySQL Workbench 8.0

Answer (score 3):

In my environment, I was able to fix this issue by repairing "Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable" both (x64) and (x86).  Yes, it sounds funny that the version I repaired was 2017 instead of 2005, but it worked for me.  Here's the steps:

- Go to `Control Panel` > `Uninstall a program`
- Highlight `Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x64)` and/or `Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x86)`
- Click `Change` button
- Click `Repair`
- The installer may prompt you to reboot your machine
- Repeat the steps above if both x64 and x86 versions are installed.

After rebooting machine, I was able to install MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 2):

I have been in the same situation and I resolved this problems following the next steps:

Using Windows

1. Open Control Panel.
2. Select Install and uninstall programs
3. Find  Visual C++ Redistributable 2015.
4. Select it, Wait for the dialog box, and  choose Repair
5. Later, reapeat the same step, in (x86) version.

Remember, Apply this only 2015 version.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I had the same experience, it simply needed Administrative rights; launch with admin or launch command prompt as an admin (administrative privileges) and then launch the latest installer (I installed 8.0 successfully this way).

See below image of command prompt (must show "Administrator:" in title) and successful installation from this window

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This has been reported as a bug on the MySQL Bugs site:
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91953
other similar bugs 87570, 88000, 88338, 85908,

A common error appears to be not having .NET upto date, 
while other possible solutions include:

- Downloading mysql for visual studio 1.2.8
- Manually create the Key for Visual Studio 2015 (not recommended)
  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\Setup\VS

WorkRound that worked for me

> ```
> - stop Visual C++ 2017 dependant programs
> - remove Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable
> - install Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable
> - install 'MySQL Workbench 8.0.12'
> - run 'MySQL Workbench 8.0.12' (need to run and close before updating to 2017)
> - close 'MySQL Workbench 8.0.12'
> - re-install Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is permissions.  When running the MSI, AND if your local policy is set to  (prompt for everything), you will encounter this issue because the MSI isn't prompting for credentials to browse the registry to look and see if c++ redistributable is installed.

Solution.

Run the msi as an admin.

how i did that:

download and open the workbench msi in a msi editor, like InstEd. from within InstEd, run the package as an admin.

Answer (score 1):

Do not use the "mysql-workbench-community-8.0.17-winx64.msi" installer, instead use the "[mysql-installer-web-community-8.0.17.0.msi](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html)" installer. From within this installer install the workbench.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution to install **Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Package** is by:

1 - Select the Start button **>** All programs **>** Windows Update.

2 - In the left pane, select Check for updates.

3 - If any important updates are found, select the link to view available             updates. In the list of updates, select Service Pack for Microsoft Windows (**KB976932**) and then select **OK**.

4 - Select **Install updates**. Administrator permission required
 You might be asked for an admin password or to confirm your choice.

5 - This is Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 (KB976932)  [Page Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-GB/download/details.aspx?id=5842)

Answer (score 0):

My situation: I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ 2017 Redistributable (x64) and (x86) but the Mysql installer(8.0) requires a 2015 version.
   After I uninstalled the 2017 version to try to install a 2015 one, whatever times I did installing&uninstalling of 2015 version, the installer just could not detect that I have installed the 2015 version. Then I checked the regidit and found out that there was no key and value for the 2015 version.

**Solution:**
   Then I reinstalled the 2017 version with the 2015 version installed in my computer before. It works fine. The Mysql installer is able to detect the Microsoft Visual C++ 2015. And the regidit has the key and value for version 2015 & 2017. What's interesting is it seems that the version of 2017 & 2015 share the same key root in regidit, which is

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\VC\Runtimes\x64.`

Thanks for some of the threads which really open my thought.

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to install MySQL Workbench 8.0.12 for my windows 10 pro x64bit (version 1803) I have faced same issue but after few try i find Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable package x86 & x64 for 2008, 2010, 2012, 2013 & 2017 already installed but there is no 2015 version which is required by MySQL Workbench 8.0.12. But when i tried to install Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable 2015 it says already installed. To solved it i just uninstalled 2017 and then install 2015 after that reinstall 2017 and then installed MySQL Workbench and everything worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Copied from @miha's URL

Microsoft C++ Redistributable Repair List:

```
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable x64  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable x86  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable x64  
Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 Redistributable x86
```

1. Open Programs and Features.
   a. Start > Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features.
   b. Search > Programs and Features.
2. Select Microsoft C++ Redistributable, right-click and click on Change.
3. On Microsoft C++ Redistributable Setup, click on Repair.
4. Click on Close once setup is successful.

Answer (score 0):

An incorrect version of vc_redist.x86 was creating issue in my win 10 machine. Uninstalled this and installed vc_redist.x64. After this the workbench installation got completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update the 2017 C++ Redistributable, because that is causing the issue.
As the Mysql need 2015 C++ Redistributable, but the 2017 one has deleted the registry of 2015.
Just update it.

Go to Control Panel -> Programs -> Programs and Features.
Select Microsoft C++ Redistributable, click on Change.
Then click on Repair.
Close once setup is successful.
After that you need to restart the computer.
(Remember to update both the x86 and x64 if you have two.)

I got installed without restarting.

Answer (score 0):

**Download: The latest supported Visual C++ downloads**

download link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads-2647da03-1eea-4433-9aff-95f26a218cc0

Comment: This is just a very little beyond a link-only answer. After ignoring the link this answer boils down to "latest downloads help". It would probably considered more helpful (i.e. upvoteable) if you could explain why they help. Then you are probably quite close to the answer accepted answer by Miha. So please make more obvious the additional insight your post provides in comparison to all existing answers.

Answer (score 0):

I used the MySQLInstaller to install the required C++ Package and MySQL Workbench.

1. Download https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html
2. In the Installer: Select Products -> Select Applications -> Select MySQL Workbench
3. Add to list, click next
4. Execute installation missing package
5. Install MySQL Workbench

**Done**