# MySQL workbench installer requires Visual C++ 2015, but i have it already installed (Windows 7)

Tags: visual-c++, mysql-workbench

when i tried to install the program, it launches me this error saying i need to download and install the Visual C++ 2015, but after doing it, the installer of the visual said that i already had it installed.

I've searched and found an an apparent answer to the problem, but, neither i understand what i need to do, nor it's for windows 7, the solution it's for windows 10.

So i need a hand here because i don't quite understand what to do to install the workbench, or it is another way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried installing both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Visual C++ 2015?

Comment: Yes, i have both x86 C++ 2015, and the 2017 64-bit version wich contains the 2015 x64.

Comment: Well, here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172345/mysql-workbench-installer-requires-visual-c-2015-redistributable-package-to-be

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySql Workbench installer requires Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Package to be installed, but it already is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172345/mysql-workbench-installer-requires-visual-c-2015-redistributable-package-to-be)

Comment: i looked that question but as i said in the post, i didn't understood the solution.
but i looked again the post with more calm (i was in a hurry) and it only needed to repair the 2017 C++... (what a facepalm) sorry for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already answered: [MySql Workbench installer requires Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Package to be installed, but it already is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172345/mysql-workbench-installer-requires-visual-c-2015-redistributable-package-to-be)

(repair the 2017 C++ redistributable and it's done).